# Assigning value of a select list to model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to assign the selected item value to Model.CatId. How can I do that in script  when an item selected.
here is the select

```
<select id="DropList">
        <option value="0"> </option>
              @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
              {

                <option value="@item.Id">
                    @item.Name
                </option>
              }
        </select>
```

I want to add the selected value to Model.CatId by jquery. And go on taking other informations.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DropList').change(function () {

            var a = $('#DropList').val();
});
```

Comment: i think you did it perfectly! what's wrong with it? what else you want to know? yo got the value of selected option in `a`, so use it.

Comment: @Ashan I took the value but how can I assign the value to a Model's property (eg: Model.CatId)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the information back to the server.

The easiest way is to wrap your `<select>` in a form, and give the select a name:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <select name="CatId" .... >   
 }


<script 
      // .....
      $('#droplist').change(function() {
          $(this).closest("form").submit();
      });
```

Now add CatID to the arguments of the controller method handling the result, or do an UpdateModel.

You can also use ajax to prevent a post of the whole form.